# Unable to format code in comments nor add newlines

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting, markdown

I don't understand how to write comments to my posts (answering people). 
I need a way to create a 'new-line' and specify code, but I can't. 
Can anybody help me?

For example, see [this post I created today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442280/javascript-is-it-possible-to-concatenate-buffers-into-a-blob). As you can see, the comment is unreadable.

Comment: Edit your question to include this information instead

Comment: It's not a fault or missing feature of some kind because you **should not** do that sort of markup in comments.

Answer (score 8):

Don't post code in comments. Instead, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25442280/edit) to include that information.

Ensure you format the code nicely, with consistent indentation and using a code block. See the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info on that.

Some other minor comments on your question:

- Refrain from adding tags into your title. "*javascript-*" is unneeded.
- Don't finish questions with "Thanks", or any other sign-off/signature line.
- It's rarely necessary to add "*(EDIT:)*" style comments. Just adjust your question so that it reads neatly from start to finish.